# How to handle launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]? in Swift?

Tags: swift, appdelegate, option-type

In a Swift AppDelegate class, you get the following method:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // ...code...
    return true
}
```

The `launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?` parameter is an optional. In Objective-C this is passed as an `NSDictionary`. I'm looking to extract the `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey` from it. Here's how it's done in Objective-C:

```
NSDictionary *remoteNotification = launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];

if (remoteNotification)
{
    // ...do stuff...
}
```

How would you go about doing that in Swift?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In Swift, you'd do it like this:

```
if let remoteNotification = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] as? NSDictionary {
    // ...do stuff...
}
```

Comment: how can I log to the screen what remoteNotification contains. As the app needs to be launched from a push notification while the app attached to xcode?

Comment: The best way to see what is actually happening would be to throw a UIAlertView up with the message as the contents of the print statement you would otherwise be logging.

Answer (score 1):

I handle it in Swift like this:

```
if let remoteNotification = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] as? [NSObject : AnyObject] {
    // ... do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think for Swift 3, it would be like this:

```
if (launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.remoteNotification] as? NSDictionary) != nil {
    // ...do stuff          
}
```